# can not picklable <type 'function'>: attribute lookup__builtin__.function failed by pool.map()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The problem setting is:

1. There is a function called target I want to make multiprocessing using pool.map()
2. I am using multiprocessing module
3. It seems to be that the function using pool.map must be serialisable/pickable
4. my target function is first-level function in the module

The problem:

1. have a database connection in my target function which can not be serialized
2. I can not factor out this database connection

Is there anything I can do to get around this and use pool.map()? or something else?

I have tried to install pathos package. But its dependancy pyre provide already no tarball. And my machine has no internet connection.

Comment: Is it possible to re-establish the database connection in the subprocesses?

Comment: @mdurant thank you for your answer. haven't got your idea. Can you provide more information? or a link on this. thank you.

Comment: I mean that you can setup the cursor (python DB api), engine (sqlalchemy) or whatever from the original connection details (ip, db, username, port...). Modern databases like postgres, mysql are perfectly happy to be accessed from multiple processes simultaneously.

Comment: `Pool.map()` uses `Queue`, which doesn't accept anything that is not pickable. You can try to either implement multi-processing with `Process()`, or you can put the worker function into a separate Python and use `Pool.map()` to call `subprocess.call` to execute the Python file.